# Can not compile libsndfile code on ubuntu

Tags: c, ld, pkg-config, libsndfile

This is my first post.
I need to manipulate audios for my project so I decided to use libsnfile.
I already installed it but when I try to compile any .c program with `gcc somefile.c` or `` gcc `pkg-config sndfile` somefile.c `` it gives me "undefined" error

`` /tmp/ccGTKZdy.o: En la función `convert_to_text':
sndfile-to-text.c:(.text+0x193): referencia a `sf_readf_float' sin definir
/tmp/ccGTKZdy.o: En la función `main':
sndfile-to-text.c:(.text+0x37a): referencia a `sf_open' sin definir
sndfile-to-text.c:(.text+0x3a7): referencia a `sf_strerror' sin definir
sndfile-to-text.c:(.text+0x3e1): referencia a `sf_strerror' sin definir
sndfile-to-text.c:(.text+0x45f): referencia a `sf_close' sin definir ``

Any "sf_..." function is not defined. 
I've read that i may have to link to the library but idk how. Help.

Answer (score 1):

Calling just `pkg-config sndfile` is not enough.  It should be:

```
gcc somefile.c "$(pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile)"
```

And `$()` is recommended over backticks in command substitution these days: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006.

Also remember about including libsndfile header in your program:

```
#include <sndfile.h>
```

and add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` option to make compiler report all kinds of warnings - fix your code until there are no warnings:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic somefile.c "$(pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile)"
```

Comment: Thank for answer but it didn't work. Still giving the same error. What else can I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have sndfile installed at all? What does `pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile` say?

Comment: Im not sure if it is completed installed. That command returns this:  -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lsndfile

Comment: ok, so it should work. Post all exact steps you do and an error message you get. BTW, change your locale to English.

Comment: Ok. I just changed locale to english. What i do is.
1. Enter to the examples folder that came inside the libsndfile
2. Open terminal and type export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
3. Try to compile any .c inside with gcc "$(pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile)" -Wall -Wextra -pedantic generate.c

Comment: Then I get the following error message:

/tmp/ccsxPgxv.o: In function `encode_file':

generate.c:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `sf_open'

generate.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `sf_strerror'

generate.c:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `sf_format_check'

generate.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `sf_close'

generate.c:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `sf_open'

generate.c:(.text+0x2ef): undefined reference to `sf_strerror'

generate.c:(.text+0x31a): undefined re (...)

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Hmm, what does `file $(readlink -e /usr/lib64/libsndfile.so)` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212576/discussion-between-mario-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).